# I'm using jinja for this flask app that I'm making and when ever i run it jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined appears

Tags: jinja2

So, what I am using it for is to render a template that I have.
Here is the code it has a problem with.
`

```
@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

`
By the way this is the code in home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content
%}
<h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
  {% for note in user.notes %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ note.data }}
    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({note,id })"
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<form method="POST">
  <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br />
  <div align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I run it. It gives me a link to website. Everything there, No. I run it. It gives me a link to website. And then jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined is on my website

Answer (score 0):

Check your html file, you may accidently got a variable called user in there

Comment: Yep youve got {% for note in user.notes %} though you dont have any parameters given in your python file @Mayo

Comment: Oh, yeah I couldnt see that